# How to derive the convergence condition for $x_{n+1}=g(x_n)$ is $|g'(x_0)<1|$

Tags: numerical-methods

In the method of fixed point iteration we are looking for solutions to
$$f(x)=0,$$
by rearranging to give:
$$x=g(x)$$
we then iterate using 
$$x_{n+1}=g(x_n)$$
using an intial guess of $x_0$.
I'm struggling to understand how the taylor expansion helps us find the convergence conditions that $|g'(x_0)<1|$. I'm sure I'm doing something stupid, but I can't seem to get it out, any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is $x_0$ the initial condition of your fixed point iteration (so that $x_1=g(x_0)$ etc) or is it the desired fixed point itself (in which case $x_0=g(x_0)$)?

Comment: [Buzzwords](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-point_theorem).

Comment: $|g'(x_0)| < 1$ is a sufficient but not necessary condition for iteration with $x_1$ sufficiently close to $x_0$ to converge to $x_0$.  For example, if $g(x) = x - x^3$ and $|x_1| < 1$ then the sequence still converges to 0 (just absurdly slowly).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question centers around the following theorem.

Let $I \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ be an open interval and let $g : I \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be differentiable with a continuous derivative $g' : I \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. Suppose $g$ has a fixed point $\xi \in I$ and $|g'(\xi)|<1$. Then there exists a closed bounded interval $J \subset I$, such that $\xi \in J$, $g(J) \subseteq J$ and $g_{|J} : J \rightarrow J$ is a contraction, i.e., there exists $L \in [0,1)$ such that
$$\forall x, y \in J \: : \: |g(x) - g(y)| \leq L |x-y|.$$
Moreover, the fixed point iteration
$$ x_{n+1} = g(x_n)$$
converges to $\xi$ regardless of the choice of starting point $x_0 \in J$.

The central point is the existence of the interval $J$ and the (Lipschitz) constant $L < 1$. We will delay the proof a moment and instead focus on the convergence of the fixed point iteration. The delightful property that $g$ maps $J$ into itself ensures that the iteration is well defined for all $x_0 \in J$. Moreover, we have
$$ |\xi - x_{n+1}| = |g(\xi) - g(x_n)| \leq L |\xi - x_n|.$$
By induction on $n$ we have
$$ |\xi - x_n| \leq L^n |\xi - x_0|.$$ 
Since $L < 1$, convergence follows immediately.

Now for the construction of $J$ and the selection of $L$. By assumption, we have $|g'(\xi)| < 1$. Let $\epsilon>0$ be given by 
$$ \epsilon = \frac{1 - |g'(\xi)|}{2}.$$
By the continuity of $g'$ there exists a $\delta > 0$ such that 
$$ \forall z \in I \: : \: |\xi - z| < \delta \: \Rightarrow \: |g'(\xi) - g'(z)| < \epsilon.$$
It is clear that this property implies $|g'(z)| < 1$. Why? By the triangle inequality we have
$$ |g'(z)| \leq |g'(\xi)| + |g'(\xi) - g'(z)| < |g'(\xi)| + \frac{1-|g'(\xi)|}{2} = \frac{1+|g'(\xi)|}{2} < 1.$$
Since $I$ is an open interval we can without loss of generality assume that $(\xi - \delta, \xi + \delta) \subseteq I$. If necessary, we simply reduce $\delta$. We now define $$J = \left[\xi - \frac{\delta}{2}, \xi + \frac{\delta}{2}\right].$$
By design $J$ is a closed and bounded interval and we have $|g'(z)| < 1$ for all $z \in J$ which automatically implies that 
$$ L = \sup \{ |g'(z)| \: : \: z \in J \} < 1.$$
At this juncture the mean value theorem finally makes it appearance. Given $x, y \in J$, there exists at least one $z$ between $x$ and $y$, such that
$$ g(x) - g(y) = g'(z)(x-y).$$ 
Since $z \in J$, we have $|g'(z)| \leq L$. This completes the analysis.

---

Higher order Taylor expansions enter into the picture when higher order derivatives of $g$ exist and vanish at the fixed point, but this is perhaps a subject for another question.

Comment: Thank you loads for this exciting detailed answer. Exactly what I needed!

Answer (score 1):

First consider what happens when $g(x) = ax + b.$  Then $$|x_{n+1} - x_0| = |g(x_n) - g(x_0)| = |a| |x_n-x_0| \\ \Rightarrow \\ |x_{n+1} - x_0| = |a|^n \cdot |x_1-x_0|$$ so in this situation, $|g'(x_0)| = |a| < 1$ is necessary and sufficient for convergence when $x_1\neq x_0.$

That's how we can deduce the condition $|g'(x_0)| < 1.$  To see it works in a broader class of functions, we can use the mean value theorem (which is the "base case" of Taylor's theorem).

Specifically, if we assume $g$ is continuously differentiable in a neighborhood of $x_0$ and $|g'(x_0)| < 1$ then it is possible to choose $x_1$ such that $|g'(x)| < 1$ for all $|x - x_0| \leq |x_1-x_0|.$  Using this choice of $x_1,$ the mean value theorem effectively reduces the problem to the linear case.  From this, we can conclude that $|g'(x_0)| < 1$ is a sufficient condition for $x_n \to x_0$ for some choice of $x_1.$  (and by a similar argument, $|g'(x_0)| \leq 1$ is a necessary condition)

Comment: To clarify, $|g'(x_0)| \leq 1$ is a necessary condition to have numerically stable convergence.  It is possible for $g(x_n) = x_0$ for some $x_n \neq x_0$ independent of the value of $g'(x_0)$, but this is uninteresting numerically because even if we are insanely lucky on our choices of $x_1$ to have this occur, we would need $x_0$ to be exactly represented numerically to avoid immediate divergence _away_ from $x_0.$

Comment: Thank you for this Brian, extremely useful, this helped me derive it myself yesterday. I wish I could accept two answers!